# ack-grep throws <Invalid filter specification "tags">

Tags: ack

When I search with ack-grep I get this error,

```
$ ack-grep SearchString
Invalid filter specification "tags" at /usr/bin/ack-grep line 126.
main::_compile_file_filter('HASH(0x18cad00)', 'ARRAY(0x19d8700)') called at /usr/bin/ack-grep line 917
main::main() called at /usr/bin/ack-grep line 75
```

Answer (score 1):

Found answer for my own question.

I was trying to make ack-grep ignore "tags" file generated by ctags and added incorrect syntax to $HOME/.ackrc
Once I fixed it, the issue got resolved.

Incorrect syntax,

> --ignore-file=tags

Correct syntax,

> --ignore-file=is:tags

Comment: What version of ack are you running?  You should be getting a more helpful error.  For more about the options for specifying file filters, see the ack man page (`ack --man`) and look for "Defining your own types".

Comment: Sorry for not making it obvious. I found the solution.
I figured I was not using the right syntax in with "--ignore-file:is:tags"

Comment: I understand that you solved the problem, and I'm glad.  My concern is that you are probably using a pretty old version of ack based on the error message you are getting.  ack is currently at version 2.24, or you can get the beta for ack 3.